# How to convert input to a random type? Python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to write a function that takes inputs and converts them into random types.

e.g. input as integer and output would be random of int,str,bool or float

Comment: why? why? why? why?

Comment: @Chris_Rands : I am with you on this. Why? Why?@Nairda123 : I would suggest having an list of data types you want to convert to and, converting your input by typecasting to data type based on randomly generated index for the data type list.

Comment: `random.choice((str, int, float))(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for... as I don't see the point of doing that but I guess that this works:

```
import random

def random_type(x):
    fun = random.choice([int, float, str, bool])
    return fun(x)
```